Does causing Hezek R’iyah block the divine presence from resting?
The Gemara says:
וַיִּשָּׂא בִלְעָם אֶת עֵינָיו, וַיַּרְא אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל שֹׁכֵן לִשְׁבָטָיו״ – מָה רָאָה? רָאָה שֶׁאֵין פִּתְחֵי אׇהֳלֵיהֶם מְכֻוּוֹנִין זֶה לְזֶה, אָמַר: רְאוּיִן הַלָּלוּ שֶׁתִּשְׁרֶה עֲלֵיהֶם שְׁכִינָה
"“And Balaam lifted up his eyes, and he saw Israel dwelling tribe by tribe; and the spirit of God came upon him” (Bamidbar 24:2). The Gemara explains: What was it that Balaam saw that so inspired him? He saw that the entrances of their tents were not aligned with each other, ensuring that each family enjoyed a measure of privacy. And he said: If this is the case, these people are worthy of having the Divine Presence rest on them."
Does observing(keeping/shermirat) privacy and avoiding Hezek R’iyah facilitate the Divine Presence resting? Does not observing privacy and causing Hezek R’iyah block the Divine Presence from resting? Or was Bil'aam just paying a compliment?
Does this have anything specifically to do with Nevuah?
